# 2000 census data by block group

Tags: data-request, usa, census

I need Population & Housing Unit Counts for Blocks (all the states) from 1990, 2000, and 2010 Census. I downloaded 2010 and 1990 from the following links, but can not find the corresponding data for 2000 census.

Does anybody know how to get such a data for Blocks for each state from 2000 census?

American FactFinder does not have the information for housing units for blocks and even for the population, it should be downloaded for each county separately (time-consuming for the whole US).

2010:
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html

1990:
https://www2.cdc.gov/nceh/lead/census90/house11/download.htm

Comment: Your question header says "by block group" but the text refers to blocks. You should clarify which you want, although both are available in the same bulk data releases.

Answer (score 4):

Block level data for the 2000 Census is included in the Summary File 1 (SF1) release here: https://www2.census.gov/census_2000/datasets/Summary_File_1/  The rather impenetrable technical docs for the SF1 release can be found [here](https://www.census.gov/prod/cen2000/doc/sf1.pdf).

Each state has a "geoheader" file and 39 segmented files which together contain all of the tables for all of the geographies in a state. Details can be found in documentation on that server, although some of the URLs in documentation are no longer available. Within these state-level files, the rows can be joined using the "LOGRECNO" column (the 5th column in the data files, 7th column in the geoheaders), although note that the LOGRECNO values are only unique within each state folder. My first time working with Census 2000 data, I thought they were true unique IDs for the place associated with estimates in a row.

For population counts, you want table P1, which is in file segment 1; for housing unit counts, you want table H1, which is in file segment 37.  I'm pretty sure that you just need the first six columns of each of the two segment files -- the first five would be for joining with the geoheaders, and the sixth would be the single data column, for P1 or H1 depending on which segment file you had.

Newcomers to 2000 census data may benefit from a tool called [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.1/), which has a program, [`in2csv`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.1/scripts/in2csv.html) which is useful for parsing fixed-width files like the geoheader file. A suitable "schema" for the 2000 census can be downloaded [from github](https://github.com/wireservice/ffs/blob/master/us/census/census2000_geo_schema.csv).